# Generic collection with IEqualityComparer in constructor

Tags: c#, collections

Is there any collection in framework like that?

```
public class DesiredCollection<T>
{
    public DesiredCollection(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) 
    {
    }
}
```

Requirements:

- generic collection;
- IEqualityComparer or lambda-expression to determine equality;
- no need to define key type;
- getting item by key;
- getting all items as IEnumerable.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  What behavior do you need the collection to perform?

Comment: @artplastika When you say *no need to define key type; getting item by key;*, I think you need a `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`. You can specify your `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various collections take `IEqualityComparer<T>` in their constructors (usually as one overload out of several). In particular, [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) fall into this category. They use the equality comparer to check for the existence of keys / elements.

However, you haven't really expressed anything other than the need for a constructor taking an equality comparer. Presumably you'll need more than that... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, I accept this as an answer. When I was designing I forgot that I need to get particular item from collection by key, so Dictionary is inevitable :)